# How to Pipe Observables

Tags: rxjs, observable

I want to test every value an observable emits, and if it fits certain criteria, then error-out the result, otherwise pass the value on. Is there an operator for this?

Comment: I think the operator you're looking for is [every](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-every)

Comment: BTW, for this kind of question please use Gitter instead of stackoverflow

Comment: what's Gitter? and why is it better than stackoverflow?

Comment: also, how do you send an error via 'every'?

Comment: How about `observable | async | myotherpipe`?

Comment: @f.khantsis Gitter is not "better" than stackoverflow it's different. You can create a channel on GItter for every Github project. Major projects have a Gitter room ;) It's more appropriate than SO here because you don't have anything that you've try, you don't have any code or researches written in your question. Take a look here : https://gitter.im/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I didn't mean Angular pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `throw`, you can separate cases that do not match the condition, but they will terminate immediately.

```
let source = Observable.of(1,2,3);

source
    .mergeMap(value => {
        if (value > 1) {  // condition
            return Observable.throw(`Out Of Condition: ${value}`);
        }
        return Observable.of(value);
    })
    .subscribe(
        value => console.log(`Next: ${value}`),
        error => console.log(`Error: ${error}`),
        () => console.log('completed')
    );
```

**Result:**

```
Next: 1
Error: Out Of Condition: 2
```

You can also think of ways like `stdout` and `stderr` in bash. For this, additional information was augmented. In this case, it does not end in the middle.

```
const stdout = 1;
const stderr = 2;
let source = Observable.of(1,2,3);

source
    .map(value => {
        if (value > 1) {  // condition
            return [stderr, value];
        }
        return [stdout, value];
    })
    .subscribe(channel_value => {
        let channel = channel_value[0];
        let value = channel_value[1];

        if (channel == stdout) {
            console.log(`stdout: ${value}`);
        }
        else if (channel == stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${value}`);
        }
    });
```

**Result:**

```
stdout: 1
stderr: 2
stderr: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right answer, but what worked for me, was `Observable.create`

```
Observable.create((observer: Observer) => 
  sourceObservable.subscribe((val: Value) => {
    if(condition)
      observer.next(val);
    else
      observer.error(val);
  }, observer.error, observer.complete)
)
```

This is very inelegant. I hope there is a better way